# stat_function produces flat line from function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")

f <- function(x)
{
    if (x >= 2) {-1 + x + 0.3}
    else {0}    
}

graph <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 10)), aes(x))
graph <- graph + stat_function(fun=f)
print(graph)
```

That unexpectedly produces the following graph:

[image]

But when I use the function on its own the result is the expected:

```
> f(1)
[1] 0
> 
> f(3)
[1] 2.3
> 
> f(7)
[1] 6.3
```

How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the following warning:

```
> f(c(0,10))
[1] 0
Warning message:
In if (x >= 2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The first element in `c(0,10)` is not greater than or equal to 2, and since your function was not designed to operate on a vector of values, it only evaluated the first element and returned a single `0` - which is what your call to `print(graph)` displays. This actually gave the same warning message as above:

```
> plot(graph)
Warning message:
In if (x >= 2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

You just need to vectorize your function:

```
f2 <- function(x)
{
  ifelse(x>=2,-1+x+.3,0)
}
##
> f2(c(0,10))
[1] 0.0 9.3
##
graph2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 10)), aes(x))
graph2 <- graph2 + stat_function(fun=f2)
print(graph2)
```

[image]

Comment: R looks like a simply language, but it has some crazy weirdness.